# Is it possible to declare an object of a class as a member variable of same class?

Tags: c++, class

This may sound silly, I don't know.

```
class Example {
 private:
       Example x; 
 public:
       //Methods
 };
```

It is possible in JAVA, but in C++ it is showing error. *(field 'x' has incomplete type )*

How can I do this in C++? If not what are other ways to do the same. I know one, pointers :) Anything else?

Also, I would be happy to know, what restricts to do the same in C++.

Thanks.

Comment: A class that contains itself. What is it's size (`sizeof(Example)`)?

Comment: Java only supports reference semantics for user defined types...

Answer (score 1):

Ref: [Self Referential Structures](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/self-referential-structures/)

This is not allowed in c++ as it will be recursive structure.
However, you can use a Pointer having the address of same class type(Self Referential Pointer)

```
class A
{
    A* aObj; // Self Referential Pointer
}
```

Comment: Link is of questionable value. It starts off good, then wanders into graph-specific details that aren't relevant in the general case.

Comment: got the idea of recursive structure. Is it possible to do the same by any other method except pointers?

Comment: Since in the original question `Example` clearly owns `x`, then in your example `aObj` should be `std::unique_ptr<A> aObj` instead of `A* aObj`. You'll need to implement copy assignment and copy construction explicitly.

Comment: Worth mentioning also the possibility of `std::shared_ptr` and `std::weak_ptr` along with `std::unique_ptr` proposed by @FrançoisAndrieux. See also: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63365537/c-instance-of-same-class/63365597#63365597